Python XML Signing, bad signature when using detached
We're using Python Signxml (https://pypi.org/project/signxml/) to sign an XML message that is going to a Modirum MPI server - however we are getting a "bad signature" error and we can't figure out why - so any assistance would be appreciated.
Here is the code:
import os
import base64
import requests
import signxml

from lxml import etree as lxml_ET
from signxml import XMLSigner, XMLVerifier, CanonicalizationMethod

TERM_URL = os.environ.get('TERM_URL', 'https://somedomain.url')
SELF_ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('SELF_ENVIRONMENT', 'staging')

POST_URL = 'https://modirumServerHere/url/things'


class ModiumSignXML:
    def __init__(self, xml):
        self.xml = xml

    def sign_xml(self, xml, message_id):

        cert, key = [open(f, "rb").read() for f in ("staging.cert.crt", "staging.private.key")]

        reference_uri_link = f'''#{message_id}'''

        temp = f'''<ModirumMPI xmlns="http://www.modirum.com/schemas/mpiapi" xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                        {xml}
                    </ModirumMPI>'''


        data = lxml_ET.fromstring(temp.encode('utf-8'))
        signer = XMLSigner(method=signxml.methods.detached,
                           c14n_algorithm=signxml.CanonicalizationMethod.CANONICAL_XML_1_0)
        signed_root = signer.sign(data, key=key, cert=cert, reference_uri=reference_uri_link)
        data_serialized = lxml_ET.tostring(signed_root)

        temp = temp.replace('</ModirumMPI>', data_serialized.decode('utf-8') + '</ModirumMPI>')

        # data_parsed = lxml_ET.fromstring(temp)
        XMLVerifier().verify(temp.encode('utf-8'), x509_cert=cert, id_attribute=reference_uri_link)

        return temp

    def process(self, pan, expiry, amount, exponent, description, currency, term_url, transaction_id, merchant_id,
                merchant_name):

        # message_id = f"{merchant_name}{transaction_id}"
        message_id = "M1561102563170" #Hardcoded for testing

        xid = str(transaction_id).zfill(20).encode('utf-8')
        xid = base64.b64encode(xid).decode('utf-8')

        to_encrypt = f'''
        <Message md="{transaction_id}" merchantId="{merchant_id}" messageId="{message_id}" version="4.0">
            <Request>
                <EnrollmentRequest>
                    <Parameters>
                        <pan>{pan}</pan>
                        <expiry>{expiry}</expiry>
                        <deviceCategory>0</deviceCategory>
                        <purchAmount>{amount}</purchAmount>
                        <exponent>{exponent}</exponent>
                        <description>{description}</description>
                        <currency>{currency}</currency>
                        <termUrl>{term_url}</termUrl>
                        <TDS2Attributes>
                            <Attribute name="TDS2.transType">01</Attribute>
                        </TDS2Attributes>
                        <xid>{xid}</xid>
                    </Parameters>
                </EnrollmentRequest>
            </Request>
        </Message>'''

        xml = self.sign_xml(to_encrypt, message_id)

        print("REQUEST")
        print("=========="*10)
        print(xml)
        print("=========="*10)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")

        return xml

    def post_xml(self, xml):
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}

        r = requests.post(POST_URL, data=xml, headers=headers)

        print("RESPONSE")
        print("=========="*10)
        print(r.text)
        print("=========="*10)
        print("")
        print("")
        print("")


def main():
    pan = '4111111111111111'
    expiry = '2312'
    amount = '100'
    exponent = '2'
    description = 'Test'
    currency = '710'
    term_url = TERM_URL
    transaction_id = '90010'
    merchant_id = '123456'
    merchant_name = 'TestMerchant'

    test = ModiumSignXML('')
    xml = test.process(pan=pan, expiry=expiry, amount=amount, exponent=exponent, description=description,
                       currency=currency, term_url=term_url, transaction_id=transaction_id, merchant_id=merchant_id,
                       merchant_name=merchant_name)
    test.post_xml(xml)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

Essentially the function sign_xml does the signing and then verification - and that's where the error comes in. According to the spec, it needs to be a detached signature, appearing after the last "message" and before the end of the </modirumMpi> XML tag.
We've compared the outputted code to spec docs and other working logs and can't see anything different, yet our verification fails both locally and on the MPI server. So any help would be grand!
We tried various things - including the different signing methods and no joy on any of them. We have re-verified the cert and the key and they are both fine and have been extracted from the same pfx file.
